# If I switch a private GitHub repository to public, will my edit history also be public?

Tags: git, github, repository, private-repository

I have been working on a project in a private GitHub repository, which I would like to make public.

However, I would like NOT to share all my previous edits to the project, but just show edits from the time the project goes public on.

Is this possible? Or should I instead make a new repository from scratch and upload my final, edited files there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide history, you **have do not have** it. Thus - yes, create new repo from the files at HEAD of current.